# How to change all class name in ajax response?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have response data like this:

```
    <div class="blog-post">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="blog-post">Eum perferendis nisi vitae et.</div>
    <div class="blog-post">Accusantium odit molestias, excepturi iusto.</div>
    <div class="blog-post">Maxime assumenda eaque cum, mollitia.</div>
```

I try to add new class in `div.blog-post` by using `data.replace`, however it only changed once:

```
    $.ajax({
        success:function(data){
            data = data.replace('blog-post', 'blog-post is-ready');
        }
    }
```

This is output:

```
<div class="blog-post is-ready">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div class="blog-post">Eum perferendis nisi vitae et.</div>
<div class="blog-post">Accusantium odit molestias, excepturi iusto.</div>
<div class="blog-post">Maxime assumenda eaque cum, mollitia.</div>
```

How to replace whole class name `blog-post` to `blog-post is-ready`?

Comment: You can try using `/blog-post/g` to replace all instances of `blog-post`. Your code only replaces first occurance.

Comment: try `data = data.replace(/blog-post/g , 'blog-post is-ready');`

Comment: Or if you are putting the result into the page, you can create a jQuery object of the elements first, then use `$('.blog-post', $data).addClass('is-ready');`

Comment: Thank @PhaniKumarM awd + Rhumborl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.split('blog-post').join('blog-post is-ready'))
```